# Netbeans CSS3 Support

Tags: netbeans, css

I've found few pages about Netbeans and date of CSS3 implementation.

According to them, CSS3 should be implemented in Netbeans since 6.X version.

Am I blind or the support is still missing in 7.0.1 ?

Links:

- http://forums.netbeans.org/topic23063.html
- http://wiki.netbeans.org/TS_60_CSSeditor

Comment: There's also the following http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB71#Support_for_CSS3

Comment: There are a lot of improvements in NB 7.1 dev version. Install and try it (it works just fine side by side with other NB installations).

Comment: Ahhh, completely missed this, can any of you guys put this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of improvements of CSS handling (including CSS3 support) in NB 7.1. You can install and try the latest [development version](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) (weekly build, it works just fine side by side with other NB installations).